# How can I detect only mouseover and not touchstart i IE?

Tags: javascript

I have both mouseover and touchstart event attached to an element. I want the mouse hover to occur only when the user is using mouse, and touchstart to occur only when user taps on it on a touch screen. In IE, I use `pointerdown` event, but this captures both of them. There is also `MSGestureStart` that can detect touchstart, but mouseover still fires. How can I differentiate `mousehover` and `tocuhstart` in IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting that the browser has no mouse and is touch-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838680/detecting-that-the-browser-has-no-mouse-and-is-touch-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. In i have find some idea here:

[some idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838680/detecting-that-the-browser-has-no-mouse-and-is-touch-only)

Probably if you use has suggested some libraries or plugin you can find a good solution but i don't know if you can and want.

Comment: Generally better to flag the question as a duplicate rather than answer with a link to the duplicate question.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand this feature...the next time i will use it

Comment: Flag > It is a duplicate ;)