# Check if mouse exists to hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

How can I check if the user has a cursor to hover on things, preferably using javacscript? (Using bootstrap too)

```
if (hasCursor()) {
  doCode();
}
```

I tried just checking if it is a touch device, but my laptop is a 2-in-1, so I cant test it.

Comment: I guess it will help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838680/detecting-that-the-browser-has-no-mouse-and-is-touch-only/52854585#answer-52854585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use the official interface

You are testing for the ability to hover, which is currently in practice synonymous with having a cursor, but might not be in future. So use the `any-hover` query that tests whether the user has any method of hovering.

```
if(window.matchMedia("(any-hover: none)").matches) {
    doCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dude! Should work.

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as correct. 8-)